# Can I Access Hard Drive Files from Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, hard-drive, windows-8

Here's the thing. My windows computer is giving my a hard time getting to use my OS and my files stored. I am planning on install Ubuntu 14.04 on a USB Flash and then I will try to get access to my files so that I can copy them over to an external HDD. Will this work? If not, can another method be suggested to me? Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 5):

Yes it should work.

When you boot into the live USB:

1. Open `disks` (press <kbd>windows</kbd> key and type in `disks`)
2. Select the hard drive you are talking about and click mount.

Then you will be able to access the files with the file manager (called Files).

The external hard drive should automount so you shouldn't have any trouble with that.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, your Windows drive will automatically be mounted. Open `Files` and click on `+ Other Locations` to access it.

Comment: The question is seven years old and refers to a Ubuntu version that's long out of support. I don't think expanding the answer will serve any purpose.